# What is the domain name in this LDAP connection string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ldap

I am a beginner in LDAP. Could anybody please tell me what is the domain name in this LDAP connection string:

```
connectionString="LDAP://AD/dc=Demo, dc=Local"
```

whether it is `AD` or `Demo` or `Local`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dc` means "domain component", and are read from most-to-least specific order, so the DNS domain name is "demo.local".

"AD" is the hostname of the LDAP server to connect to.

Other LDAP path components like `ou` and `cn` refer to containers and objects in the directory hierarchy, so `ldap://domainController/cn=Foobar,ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=local` refers to an object called "`Foobar`" inside a container called "`Users`" within a directory for the domain name "`domain.local`"

Comment: this is the first decent explanation about using LDAP I came across, thank you!